# Is it possible to get list of projects sorted by number of issues?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to find projects containing most issues within Jira repository. Looking at the documentation, I couldn't find anything out-of-the-box to get such list (or even to get all project and the number of issues in there).

Is such thing possible or do I have to get all projects, read number of issues in there and sort them manually?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this with JIRA out of the box, but this could be done easily with a python script. If you want me to post some code let me know.

Comment: The REST API suggests using this
yourjira.example.com/rest/api/2/project

Comment: @ChrisGraf I'm not using Python in my project, but I'm able to write something like that myself :) I was just hoping it won't be needed, Jira's API is pretty big and I thought I was missing something.

Comment: @mdoar Does it give me number of issues in each project or way to sort results by that number?